# Either in or under

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence is the usage of **in** incorrect?

> One of the most important uses of drones in the Indian context, however, is their use for settlement of compensation **in** crop insurance schemes.

I think it is correct because one of the meanings of **in** is **concerning**. So here it can be interpreted as **compensation concerning crop insurance schemes**.

But according to my answer keys **in** is wrong, instead **under** should be used.

Comment: Without any further context to the question, there is no reason to think that **in** is "wrong." Both **in** and **under** form grammatical sentences.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because I suspect the final word is meant to be plural: *schemes*. 
If it is 'scheme' then it needs the definite article: *the scheme*. (Or perhaps *any scheme*) Little mistakes like these cause us headaches!

You need **the** before "settlement".

You don't need to repeat **use** ("uses"..."use").

You are right that **in** can mean *concerning*. But *concerning* is not what is needed here. Your sentence simply means these schemes *include* matters of compensation.

I imagine these crop-insurance schemes have been imposed by government or local authorities, in which case they are like guidelines **according to which** or laws **under which** we do such-and-such.

For example:

*Under new laws, visitors will be searched on entering the Houses of Parliament.*

Or:

*According to new guidelines people with symptoms of the virus should not visit their relatives in Durham.*

So.

> One of the most important uses of drones in the Indian context,
>   however, is in the settlement of compensation under crop-insurance
>   schemes.

I'm sure it doesn't fit your answer keys but I would separate the repeated "in the" by re-phrasing it:

> In the Indian context, however, one of the most important uses of
>   drones is in the settlement of compensation under crop-insurance
>   schemes.

Comment: Sorry, it was schemes, now I have put it right

Comment: @Kshitij Singh Thanks, Kshitij! :-)